# deserializing Static properties using json.net?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Hi guys I have a JSON like the one below

```
{
  "totals": {
    "tokenType": "string",
    "tokenDenomination": "double",
    "count": "int"
  },
  "IDCode": "string",
  "Key": "string"
}
```

and c# code to deserialize in to object is

```
internal class GetTokenRootInfo
{
    public  static Totals totals{ get; set;}
    public  static string IDCode{ get; set;}
    public  static string Key{ get; set;}
}
```

When I use `jsonconvert.DeserializeObject<gettokenrootinfo>(json);`
nothing is being set and every var is a null.

But if I remove static types then everything works.

Can any one tell me the reason why static types are not working when deserializing the object?

Comment: Because they're static? Seriously, I'm guessing that there might be some misuse of static members going on because it doesn't make a lot of sense to deserialize data into static members.

Comment: @KeithPayne One exception is when you use a static config class. It's useful to have config static for ease of access. A static constructor can load properties from disk and set them. (De)serializing the config class means you can simply us  `Config.MaxConnections`, `Config.Save()`, `Config.Load()`, etc...

Comment: @Keith: it is extremely useful; you have many cases where an app may need access to global settings for its operation; And building some cosmetic scaffolding to access data is not necessarily a priority.

Answer (score 7):

If you really want to deserialize to static members on the class, you can explicitly mark them with a `[JsonProperty]` attribute, and that will allow it to work:

```
internal class GetTokenRootInfo
{
    [JsonProperty("totals")]
    public static Totals totals { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("IDCode")]
    public static string IDCode { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Key")]
    public static string Key { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks @brain yes i have already done it after a bit of research.