# how to deserialize json (newtonsoft) into nested static classes

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a nested class with static properties like this:

```
public class A {
    public class B {
        public static string BString = null;
    }
}
```

Here is the JSON:

```
{
    B {
        "BString" : "Hello"
    }
}
```

I want to deserialize this JSON so that it sets the nested static value (A.B.BString should contain the string Hello). I don't know a lot about newtonsoft but is there a way to get it to do this without me having to instantiate the B class. **I don't want to have to change the class at all to get this to work.** I know you can add the [JsonProperty] to static properties to get it to deserialize properly but this does not work with nested classes.

Comment: Deserialization is about instances. so you might be heading down the wrong track here. (And that data snippet isn't valid JSON.)

Comment: JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class Name>(JsonParams);

Comment: This is not really possible unless you actively fight the serialization library. As @Wormbo mentioned, JSON represents *objects*, not namespaces, and typically not static variables. It absolutely is possible to read your custom logic when reading from `Newtonsoft`, but there's almost definitely a better way to do what you need.

Comment: Duplicate of [Why can't JSON .Net serialize static or const member variables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24336597/why-cant-json-net-serialize-static-or-const-member-variables) or [deserializing Static properties using json.net?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22605529/deserializing-static-properties-using-json-net).

Answer (score 1):

In general you can't use serialization on static classes. In the case of having a list of two different A-classes, which class would win the race and set the static B-value?

**Question:** 
Is it really necessary for you to use a nested (static) class? Whats the reason behind it? Why don't you use a non-nested class?

If you really want to achieve it, there might be a Workaround: Make a new property, in which the static value is set and retrieved. Hopefully this new property will be (de)serialized.

See this dirty example:

```
public class A
{
    public B SetBProperty 
    { 
        get { return B.BString; } 
        set { B.BString = value; } 
    }

    public class B {
        public static string BString = null;
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, that in case of the `List<A>` (de)serialization the last (de)serialized item would win and set the value.